# AWS start document analysis using textract not working

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-textract

I am doing a project for my school where I am supposed to do a document analysis on a form using textract and run that output to A2I where the algorithm will determine if the form is approved, rejected or review needed. This textract lambda function should be triggered once a document is uploaded to S3. I am however getting syntax errors when I follow this documentation; https://docs.aws.amazon.com/textract/latest/dg/API_StartDocumentAnalysis.html

My code is :

```
import urllib.parse
import boto3

print('Loading function')

##Clients
s3 = boto3.client('s3')
textract = boto3.client('textract')

def analyzedata(bucketName,documentKey):
    print("Loading")
    AnalyzedData= textract.StartDocumentAnalysis("DocumentLocation": { 
      "S3Object": { 
         "Bucket": "bucketName",
         "Name": "documentKey",
      })
    detectedText = ''

    # Print detected text
    for item in AnalyzedData['Blocks']:
        if item['BlockType'] == 'LINE':
            detectedText += item['Text'] + '\n'
            
    return detectedText
      
def writeTextractToS3File(textractData, bucketName, createdS3Document):
    print('Loading writeTextractToS3File')
    generateFilePath = os.path.splitext(createdS3Document)[0] + '.csv'
    s3.put_object(Body=textractData, Bucket=bucketName, Key=generateFilePath)
    print('Generated ' + generateFilePath)





def lambda_handler(event, context):
    #print("Received event: " + json.dumps(event, indent=2))

    # Get the object from the event and show its content type
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = urllib.parse.unquote_plus(event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key'], encoding='utf-8')
    try:
        detectedText = analyzedata(bucket, key)
        writeTextractToS3File(detectedText, bucket, key)
        
        return 'Processing Done!'
        
        
        
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error getting object {} from bucket {}. Make sure they exist and your bucket is in the same region as this function.'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
```

The code is not yet complete but I am already getting syntax errors:

```
  "errorMessage": "Syntax error in module 'lambda_function': invalid syntax (lambda_function.py, line 13)",
  "errorType": "Runtime.UserCodeSyntaxError",
  "stackTrace": [
    "  File \"/var/task/lambda_function.py\" Line 13\n        AnalyzedData= textract.Start_Document_Analysis(\"DocumentLocation\": { \n"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [boto3 docs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/textract.html#Textract.Client.start_document_analysis), your syntax should be more like:

```
AnalyzedData= textract.start_document_analysis(DocumentLocation={ 
  "S3Object": { 
     "Bucket": "bucketName",
     "Name": "documentKey",
  })
```

Also note that the `FeatureTypes` parameter is listed as required.

Comment: Omg this solved it. Can I ask tho, if the syntax is start_document_analysis, why didn't the aws documentation state that? They just stated StartDocumentAnalysis.. Really misleading for beginners like myself

Comment: I don't know that. I guess the API docs are for the web API, and the boto3 docs are specifically for the Python client?

Comment: Hmm, that makes sense. Could you help me take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62900687/aws-textract-form-analysis-get-document-analysis-syntax-error-how-should-i-writ if you have the time? Its the continuation from this question where I am using get_document_analysis this time to get the results. Thank you again ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should try to pip install awscli

`pip install awscli`

or pip3 if that works better

Then import and try running the code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a starting curly bracket character for this.

```
AnalyzedData= textract.StartDocumentAnalysis("DocumentLocation": { # missing { in this line
  "S3Object": { 
     "Bucket": "bucketName",
     "Name": "documentKey",
  })
```